# Bad Access when saving to standardUserDefaults

Tags: iphone, memory-management, nsuserdefaults

For some reason, when I try to save one string to NSUserDefaults, I get a bad access error.

```
NSString *apikey = @"key";
NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:apikey forKey:@"apiKey"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

The line that it gives bad access on is `[defaults setObject:apikey forKey:@"apiKey"];`

I haven't released either apikey or defaults, yet it always gives me bad access. I am wondering how to get around this.

EDIT:
SOLVED

It seems that `[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:apikey forKey:@"apiKey"];`
did the trick as a replacement for the line that was causing the exception.

Comment: Did you try NSString *apiKey = [NSString stringWithString:@"key"];

Comment: And btw accept some answers if you want people to help you here.

Comment: it must be something else. i tried your code, its fine. Post some more code about how u getting the nsstring?

Comment: or try  NSString *apiKey = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"key"];

Answer (score 1):

Are you really sure in your real code it does not start with:

```
NSString *apikey = "key";
```

Instead of an objective-C string?  Or that it's not initialized in some other way?  When you run Analyse, does it give warnings for any lines of code?